# Android: Expandable Listview - Load Child content from remote database

Tags: android, database, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I have an `ExpandableListView` with Group headers which wont change. Now I want to bind children of the group with different data from remote database such as `MySQL` or `MSSQL`. I have already done this for normal `ListView` using `JSON`, I have no idea how to implement it for `ExapandableListView`.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: maybe you should chech tutorials? http://androidexample.com/Custom_Expandable_ListView_Tutorial_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=107&aaid=129

Comment: i think i can make sample for you, but i don't really get you goal here

Comment: @NikMyers: Goal is, I have different data in remote database. I need to populate it in my elv. For example I have prescription data which is grouped based on prescription type like Inpatient, outpatient, etc. Based on this I have created headers, when I click on my header relevant prescription should load below that. Hope you understood.

Comment: I ment what is the goal of question? You want to have an emaple of creating dummy ExpandableListView just as a example of how to do it in your app? Or you want someone to write code for your specific case?

Comment: @NikMyers: Write code for specific case. I know how to implement ELV, but I dont know how to work with remote database and populate child items.

Comment: As you said you have worked with pasring JSON for ListView. So, in that case, that makes everything easy for you. Also you have Group headers which won't change, then do one thing populate a json response via web service which will have info in such a way each JSONObject will have childrens' records against each Group Header. And then you can parse it at app end and load on view.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto: can you please elaborate where to put what? Can I put elv in ListFragment/Fragment. If there is any example it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. I created three different `ArrayList`, one `List<String>` for header and one `HashMap`. I populated `ArrayList`  using `AsyncTask`. Then based on one specific value, I added the values to each `ArrayList` and added the child arraylist and header arraylist to `HashMap` as below.

```
JSONObject responseObj = null;
listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<PatPrescriptionList>>();

try {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    responseObj = new JSONObject(response);
    JSONArray patPrescListObj =   responseObj.getJSONArray("patPrescriptionList");

    ArrayList<PatPrescriptionList> patPrescList_MedClerking = new ArrayList<PatPrescriptionList>();
    for (int i=0; i<patPrescListObj.length(); i++){
        JSONObject patPrescInfo = patPrescListObj.getJSONObject(i);
        if(patPrescInfo.optString("PRTYPCode").equals("CC_MEDCLERK")){
           PatPrescriptionList patPresc = gson.fromJson(patPrescInfo.toString(), PatPrescriptionList.class);
           patPrescList_MedClerking.add(patPresc);                  
         }
         else if(patPrescInfo.optString("PRTYPCode").equals("CC_FORADMIN")){
           PatPrescriptionList patPresc = gson.fromJson(patPrescInfo.toString(), PatPrescriptionList.class);
           patPrescList_InpatMedication.add(patPresc);
         }
         else if(patPrescInfo.optString("PRTYPCode").equals("CC_LVMED")){
           PatPrescriptionList patPresc = gson.fromJson(patPrescInfo.toString(), PatPrescriptionList.class);
           patPrescList_LeaveMedication.add(patPresc);
           }
        else if(patPrescInfo.optString("PRTYPCode").equals("CC_DISCHMED")){
          PatPrescriptionList patPresc = gson.fromJson(patPrescInfo.toString(), PatPrescriptionList.class);
          patPrescList_DischargeMedication.add(patPresc);
          }
        else if(patPrescInfo.optString("PRTYPCode").equals("CC_OPCLERK")){
         PatPrescriptionList patPresc = gson.fromJson(patPrescInfo.toString(), PatPrescriptionList.class);
         patPrescList_OutpatClerking.add(patPresc);
        }
        else if(patPrescInfo.optString("PRTYPCode").equals("CC_OP_FORADMIN")){
         PatPrescriptionList patPresc = gson.fromJson(patPrescInfo.toString(), PatPrescriptionList.class);
         patPrescList_OutpatMedication.add(patPresc);
        }

}

listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0),patPrescList_MedClerking);
listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1),patPrescList_InpatMedication);
listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2),patPrescList_LeaveMedication);
listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(3),patPrescList_DischargeMedication);
}

listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(getActivity(), listDataHeader, listDataChild);
expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

}
catch (JSONException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```